# Passing time.Time as parameter to generic function

Tags: go

Trying to use generics with `time.Time`.
The general goal was to accept `time.Time` or milliseconds as `int64`

This code return the error:

> Cannot use 'at' (type T) as the type time.Time

```
type SomeTime struct {
    At        time.Time
}

func PointFactory[T time.Time](at T) *SomeTime {
    return &SomeTime{
        At:        at,
    }
}
```

Is it possible to pass `time.Time` as parameter to generic function?
Thanks

Comment: If T is time.Time then its not a "generic" type parameter and your question as stated makes not much sense.

Answer (score 3):

The closest you can get is to cast your T param to any then use a type switch to make the desired structs:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type SomeTime struct {
    At time.Time
}

func PointFactory[T time.Time | int64](at T) *SomeTime {
    switch any(at).(type) {
    case time.Time:
        fmt.Println("time")
        return &SomeTime{
            At: v,
        }

    case int64:
        fmt.Println("int")
        return &SomeTime{
            At: time.Unix(v, 0),
        }

    }
    return nil

}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(PointFactory(int64(6)))
    fmt.Println(PointFactory(time.Now()))
}
```

[PlayGround](https://go.dev/play/p/uS3ESjfec6d)

Output:

```
int
&{1970-01-01 00:00:06 +0000 UTC}
time
&{2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001}
```

This is because the decision of the Go team:

> In an earlier version of this design, we permitted using type assertions and type switches on variables whose type was a type parameter, or whose type was based on a type parameter. We removed this facility because it is always possible to convert a value of any type to the empty interface type, and then use a type assertion or type switch on that. Also, it was sometimes confusing that in a constraint with a type set that uses approximation elements, a type assertion or type switch would use the actual type argument, not the underlying type of the type argument (the difference is explained in the section on identifying the matched predeclared type)

Comment: God I hope no one use such approach in production.

Comment: Please use `switch v := any(at).(type)` so inside the `switch` no further type assertion is needed as `v` will be of type `time.Time` and `int64` respectively to the cases. See https://go.dev/play/p/Bc6wWRwZRLG

Answer (score 1):

You may declare multiple type as such:

```
func say[T string | int](msg T) {
    fmt.Println(msg)
}

func main() {
    say(1)
    say("hello")
}
```

See [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/XD9DrbiGquk)

Now as per your question, may you redefine your functions ? You may use:

```
PointFromInt(n int) *SomeTime {...}
PointFromTime(t time.Time) *SomeTime {...}
```

Your usecase may not be a good candidate for generics. Or regular typed function may do a better job.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", PointFactory(time.Now()).At)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", PointFactory(time.Now().Unix()).At)
}

type SomeTime[T time.Time | int64] struct {
    At T
}

func PointFactory[T time.Time | int64](at T) *SomeTime[T] {
    return &SomeTime[T]{
        At: at,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `Sometime` struct is expected to accept `time.Time` or `int64` then it needs to declare it, the methods set the value to `At` what type is available

```golang
type SomeTime[T time.Time | int64] struct {
    At T
}

func PointFactoryTime(at time.Time) *SomeTime[time.Time] {
    return &SomeTime[time.Time]{
        At: at,
    }
}

func PointFactoryInt64(at int64) *SomeTime[int64] {
    return &SomeTime[int64]{
        At: at,
    }
}
```